# General margins in beamer

Tags: beamer, margins

I'm trying to set wider margins in my beamer using:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left = 1pt, text margin right = 1pt}
```

But changin the points doesn't make any difference, I can put 100pt and still get the same result.

I try to use the same margins in all frames and avoid using minipage or textblock in every frame.

Comment: I definitely can not confirm that claim. Please compare the outputs of `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}` and `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setbeamersize{text margin left = 1pt, text margin right = 1pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\end{document}`. Therefore, please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get, in which changing the `text margin` does not have any effect.

Comment: Do you have any `\usetheme` commands in your preamble? If so, place `\setbeamersize` after them.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, placing '\setbeamersize' after '\usetheme' makes it work perfectly, I didn't realize this was the error.